How to connect to neo4j via browser?
I am running my neo4j with docker container.
I can get everything to run no problem.
But I want to use the browser to connect but not sure what to put in the Connect URL.

I am using the default ports 8787. I try put bolt+s://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8787 not working. How can I resolve this?

Assuming you have docker running locally, then you would use
bolt://localhost:7687
FYI- bolt+s would be used if you've configure SSL support.

if i have ssl running https:///example.com, what do I need to do? I tried bolt+s://example.com:7687, but not working
